# Is it possible to take a local Outlook mailbox and sync it to exchange?

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007, outlook-2003

Ok so I am going through wiping some computers for a business. The business is dissolving but the user still needs their email. I logged in as that user to check their email and I only saw 1 inbox folder and I noticed that it only had a few emails in the inbox like 1 or 2. After awhile I would refresh the page and those emails would disappear.

Their email runs on an Exchange 2007 server and they are using Outlook 2003.

On the physical machine their outlook has several folders and thousands of emails. My assumption was that for some reason beyond my knowledge it wasn't syncing local folders to Exchange.

How can I force Outlook to tell Exchange to suck up all those folders and emails? Or do I need to somehow import that mailbox to Exchange? Please remember in your answer, the emails also need to go to exchange because it appears to be removing them from Exchange automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer to this was actually pretty simple. Here is the full scenario. The user had a Personal Folder mailbox setup that was pulling their Exchange account and syncing it to that Personal Folder. While at the same time the user also had their actual Exchange account setup below their personal folder setup.

It was odd because the Exchange account was only syncing to their personal folder setup and I am not quite sure how that was happening. Anyway my solution was to right click each folder and "Move To..." which I then chose the Inbox of the actual Exchange account.

I was then able to login via the Exchange web interface and see that the emails were showing up there as well as the the folder structures.